How can I get the age of the cache using the API?
I can purge the cache via Cloudflare's API https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/zone-purge
using this function:
https://gist.github.com/Greg-Boggs/73796406278cd67334db08dc052931dd
and I get a success message with a purge.
But is it possible - using the Cloudflare API or another method - to get the timestamp of the last time the cache was purged? Or return the age of the cache? Or somehow find the last time the cache was successfully purged?

Can you edit the title so that it is more descriptive? We don't even know what API you are referencing until we open the question, even though cloudflare is mentioned in tags, we still can't be sure until we open it.

I think the simplest method is to review Audit Logs, I tested it right now, and have an event "Oct 6, 2024 Purge everything".
Audit logs can be retrieved via API, and you can specify necessary event, something like this:
curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/{account_id}/audit_logs?action.type=purge_everything" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer {your_api_token}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"

Second option is to use Cloudflare Logs, but it is available only for Enterprise plan.
Also may be useful to inspect headers of HTTP response, usually they contain CF-Cache-Status and Age. These headers can be used to find the cache age per resource.

Thanks, that is a good approach. I added an API key for logs, and the Cloudflare "test" of the API Key works. But when I try the full curl command with my account ID, I get code":10000,"message":"Authentication error". This is a "free" Cloudflare account level.

For allow access to the account audit logs, you need to provide "Access: Audit Logs:Read, Account Settings:Read" permissions to your token.
I also update my curl example a little bit.

Thanks, did that. Now when I run curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/accountid/audit_logs?action.type=purge_everything" \ -H "Authorization: Bearer apiapiapikey" \ -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ --data '{"action":"purge_cache"}' I just get a blank line return in terminal, so authentication is working. I manually cleared the cache, so there are "purges" in the audit log.

you don't need to specify the --data parameter, but you need to check exact name of that action type you performed - this is purge_cache or purge_everything.

Not sure of your exact situation, but creating a function involving HTTP response headers would likely work if you dont have a work around with cloudflare. Simply writting a function and storing the data from when HTTP response headers is updated involving your purge. A cloudflare solution would likely be easier if they have one.
